# How to debug a program/view registers that require user input

Tags: debugging, assembly, nasm, x86-16, dosbox

I have an assembly program that I'm trying to test via debug, however the program usually has user input for the integers. Is there a way to debug the program and still be able to 'run' it in the sense that I can input integers into the program but then still view values in registers?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What debugger? What OS? How do you read the user input? Show us the code.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear, I'm using the nasmide debugger inside of DosBox. I'm currently using one of the Int 21H interrupts, specifically AH=01 to read user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to debug the program and still be able to 'run' it in the sense that I can input integers into the program but then still view values in registers?

Yes, any debugger worth its salt should be able to let you execute your code instruction by instruction.

For example, Borland's `Turbo Debugger` and Open Watcom `Watcom Debugger` have the `Trace Into` and `Step Over` execution options. The two are similar but not identical. The latter executes entire subroutines as part of `call subroutine` instructions and the former executes just a single instruction, whether it's `call` or not.

See how you can do it in your debugger. Look up its UI and/or documentation.

Also, debuggers commonly let you set breakpoints on instructions of your choice and execute code until a breakpoint is encountered. You can use that too.

Comment: Ok thanks.. I'm honestly not sure what debugger I'm using, though I think It's nasmide or actually just debugging in the DOS Shell. Anyway I decided to just put in some set values instead of user input which allowed me to do some basic debugging. Thanks for you help though, I may try and see if I can download one of those debuggers.

Comment: You can definitely download `wd.exe` as part of Open Watcom C/C++.

Comment: If it's regular old DEBUG (ugh...ugh...), don't try to `t`race an `int 21h` - use `p`roceed instead. That should wait for you to enter a character. As I recall, `t`racing though dos does not work well at all!

Comment: @FrankKotler You're right, `t` is doing something odd and `p` should be used instead. Just checked.